# what is difference between "org.springframework.xyz-2.5.6.A.jar" and "spring-xyz-2.5.6.RELEASE.jar"

Tags: spring

i am new to spring framework. When i try to download required jar files for spring, then there is 2 options for same classes-
**org.springframework.xyz-2.5.6.A.jar** and **spring-xyz-2.5.6.RELEASE.jar**.
I want to know what is the difference and which is recommended to use?

thanks.

Comment: Could you name a concrete example? How are you downloading the jars? Are you using Maven?

Comment: No I am not using maven. just simply download jar files one by one.

Comment: From which source do you download?

Comment: from http://grepcode.com it is showing org.springframework.xyz-2.5.6.A.jar and from mvnrepository.com it is showing mvnrepository.com

Comment: You download jars from there?

Answer (score 1):

The `org.springframework.xyz` version is the artifact ID used by SpringSource in their [Enterprise Bundle Repository](http://ebr.springsource.com/repository/app/), a self-contained set of OSGi-compliant JARs for both Spring and non-Spring artifacts.  The `spring-xyz` version is the standard non-OSGi version available on Maven Central.

If you're using OSGi then use the EBR JARs, if you're not then use the standard ones.

Answer (score 0):

The [current Maven dependency for `spring-context`](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.springframework%7Cspring-context%7C3.2.4.RELEASE%7Cjar) is

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

The resulting JAR is [spring-context-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/springframework/spring-context/3.2.4.RELEASE/spring-context-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar).

So the second name looks OK to me.